# How to take snapshot of EOS blockchain?

Tags: smart-contract, nodeos, cleos

How can I take a snapshot of EOS blockchain up to a particular block? Is the snapshot helpful to get EOS balance in each account? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [Everipedia's tool which they open sourced](https://github.com/EveripediaNetwork/airdrop).

[image]

That or you can use [EOS Essentials tool](https://github.com/EOSEssentials/EOSDrops).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is already a snapshot provided by eosauthority (one of the BPs): https://github.com/eosauthority/genesis/tree/master/snapshot-files/final/2

You can easily access and download the json file and search for public key to find out the balance.

This snapshot includes keys and balances for all registered accounts.

Comment: That is an old snapshot

Comment: Yes. I believe it was taken before the ethereum token freeze.